# Array removal of \t\n. --NodeJS--

Tags: jquery, arrays, node.js

Current array:

```
[ '3\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t3.5\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4.5' ]
```

I am trying to make it so that the numbers are like

```
[3,3.5,4,4.5]
```

Such that :

```
array[0] = 3
```

I have tried these methods[in which do not work with the string prior to being pushed into the array, possibly because it has been derived via a jquery of cheerio].

```
var trim = numbers.trim()
array.push(trim).replace(/\\n/g, '')
```

Comment: Can you not fix this at source? Removing the garbage in JS seems to be a workaround.

Comment: `arr = arr[0].split(/\s+/).map(Number);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first replace all the newline and tab character with a special character and then filter out the defined values:

```js
var array = [ '3\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t3.5\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4.5' ]
array = array[0].replace(/\n|\t/g, '&').split('&').filter(item => item);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
const arr = [ '3\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t3.5\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4.5' ]
const parsed = arr[0].split(/\s+/).map(item => Number(item));

console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry this method works too however, there are more adjustments to be made such as there are an extra [0] index on both start and end, hence why I chose the other answer. Thanks for your submission.